# Messed up Inkscape tutorial

Tags: inkscape

*Help → Tutorial → Inkscape Basic*

The tutorial is OK:

> [image]

Now I selected and moved some objects. The tutorial is still OK:

> [image]

But after undoing the last action (*Edit → Undo: Move*) it turns into this mess:

> [image]

Why, and how to correct it quickly? (*File → Revert* is slow enough.)

Comment: Looks like some kind of glitch/bug. I'm not sure how the tutorial was actually constructed or what's causing it, but ungrouping or undoing should not change fonts in surrounding text objects. Just hit revert, or copy and paste the the shapes to a new document before trying out the steps in the tutorial.  Maybe report it as a bug.

Comment: Just as a note, I tried creating some objects, and typing some text nearby. Then grouped the objects, ungrouped them, and also tried undo several times, and I can't replicate the problem, so that means its probably document specific.

Comment: @Billy, thanks for your comments, as I understood, you can replicate the problem with the tutorial document, but not with your own, newly created one.

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: @Billy, you're right, it's a bug (see my answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug #1005: [Tutorial texts too large and superposed when undoing](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1005).

Quick steps to fix it in your installation:

1. Open a tutorial and do all things as in the question, i.e. select, move, undo. The tutorial will become messed up.
2. Save this seemingly **messed** tutorial with *File → Save as...* keeping its original name, OK, Replace (i.e. replace the original tutorial).

   **Note:** Simple *File → Save* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) doesn't work because Inscape considers the document *unchanged* after the Undo operation.

From this moment *the text will never get messed up after undoing operations.*

The moved and then reverted (by undo) shapes will be still black, but by performing another operation on them (moving back and forth, group / ungroup) they will “gain back” their original colors, and moreover they obtain an “imunity” against the other change / undo.

Comment: Actually, the bug has been fixed already (or should be). The info about that just never made it back to the original bug in the inbox bug tracker.

Are you all using the latest version, 1.0.2?

Comment: No, this bug ([#1005](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1005)) is still open, as you may see. Yes, I use the latest version, 1.0.2, and the bug is still there.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've confused it with another bug that was actually fixed (this one: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/932, I'm the author of both reports).